# .NET Standard clarification

Tags: c#, .net-core

Let's say I wrote a library with .NET STANDARD 2.0 called DotNetStandardLib20 using EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.2 packages

If I reference it with a .NET Core 2.1 library I expect to have LINQ GroupBy translation working (feature added in .net core 2.1)

If I reference it with a Winform app with .Net framework 4.7 what can I expect to happen? I did the text and it compiles but doesn't seem to run: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

What I am trying to do is to develop a new application with the most recent .net core 2.1 speed capabilities and be able to use a small winform using some of the database queries of this app.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityFrameworkCore` is, in fact, a NetStandard 2.0 library ([see](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore/EFCore.csproj#L10)). So you should be able to add EntityFrameworkCore in your .NET Framework 4.7 project.

Just add the Nuget package in the same way you added it to your library.

Comment: yes please remove the screenshot. Thank you indeed adding the package to the winform project allows me to run it without the exception. Now the question is how does the project targeting .NET standard 2.0 behave when it is referenced on the .Net core 2.1 console app vs the winform app ? Shall I expect a significant difference in terms of performance ?

Comment: @sofsntp not only the performance may vary but even the behavior. If you have unit tests for your library I'd recommend you to make your test project a multi-framework project (e.g. https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/PuppeteerSharp.Tests.csproj#L3) and run tests against both frameworks.

Comment: And if you are running a. Net core 2.1 app will performance of a referenced. Net standard library vary? Let's say. Net standard 2.0 vs 2.1 assuming 2.1 is released?

Comment: It depends on your usage of the .NET Library.